# How to do statements with time value

Tags: python, django, if-statement, time

In my Django python code I want to greet the visitor according to the time of the day.
It always gives back 'Good afternoon'(even though it isn't) but can't see why.

 this is from my views.py:

```
#import time
#import datetime
#from time import strftime
#from django.utile import timezone

def greet(request):
    request.session['greet'] = 'Good day'
    currentTime = time.strftime('%H')
    int(currentTime)
    if currentTime < 12 :
        request.session['greet'] = 'Good morning'
    if currentTime >= 18 :
        request.session['greet'] = 'Good afternoon'
    else :
        request.session['greet'] = 'Good evening'

    return request.session['greet']
```

Comment: should the second `if` statement instead be an `elif` ?  Also, shouldn't "Good afternoon" be for `<18` (while also being `>=12`), and "Good evening be for `>=18` ?  I'm also curious how you are testing.  Are you using the currentTime as read by the system clock (using time.strftime())? or are you overwriting it with a value of your choosing in order to test all values (not just the time that the computer currently has ?

Comment: Note that this isn't something you would put in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#import time
#import datetime
#from time import strftime
#from django.utile import timezone

def greet(request):
request.session['greet'] = 'Good day'
currentTime = time.strftime('%H')
int(currentTime)
if currentTime < 12 :
    request.session['greet'] = 'Good morning'
elif currentTime < 18 :
    request.session['greet'] = 'Good afternoon'
else :
    request.session['greet'] = 'Good evening'

return request.session['greet']
```

Also, how are you testing ?
As written above, you can only test using the current computer's time.
In order to test your if/elif/else statement logic, you need to be able to feed in different values for currentTime (you don't want to wait for the computer's clock to change - or reset the computer clock !)

One way to do this is to overwrite the value for currentTime.
For example:

```
...
currentTime = time.strftime('%H')   
int(currentTime)

# temp code for testing various values of currentTime. 
# Try values: below, at, and above each "breakpoint" for the if/elif/else statements.
# For example: 5, 12, 13, 17, 18, 22
currentTime = 5

if currentTime < 12 :
    request.session['greet'] = 'Good morning'
...
```

Once you have verified the logic of your statements, you can delete the "testing" code.

(Note I use Python, but not Django, so there may be a slight difference in syntax, but the logic is valid.)

Answer (score 1):

### Observations

- `int(currentTime)` will do nothing, as you are not assigning the generated integer value to any variable. I have corrected this in my code to be on the line above, i.e. `currentTime = int(time.strfttime('%H'))`;
- You have commented out your `import` statements, so I don't think any of those packages are going to be imported (haven't used Django though, so I'm not sure about this one);
- As it currently is, you are never going to get a greeting of good morning. If it is in the morning the greeting will be set to "Good morning", **and then** the next `if` / `else` statement will run - if the time is greater than `18` hours, it will say "Good afternoon", otherwise it will say "Good Evening".

### Solution

Try an `if`, `elif` and `else` block, where you clearly define the ranges of each greeting.

For example:

```
def greet(request):
    request.session['greet'] = 'Good day'
    currentTime = int(time.strftime('%H'))
    if currentTime < 12 :
        request.session['greet'] = 'Good morning'
    elif currentTime < 18 :
        request.session['greet'] = 'Good afternoon'
    else :
        request.session['greet'] = 'Good evening'

    return request.session['greet']
```

This means that:

- if the hour is less than `12`, it should say "Good morning";
- if the hour is greater than `11` and less than `18` (remember `if` / `elif` / `else` blocks always exit at the first condition which is true, so because it didn't exit at the first condition, we know that the hour is not less than `12`, thus it must at least be greater than `11`) it should say "Good afternoon";
- and otherwise (if neither of these conditions is true, and thus the hours are greater than `17`), it will say "Good evening".